# How can I convert a thread to a GUI thread?

Tags: windows

I'm reading [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/exploit-protection-reference?view=o365-worldwide), and quote:

> This mitigation prevents calls into win32k.sys by blocking a thread from converting itself into a GUI thread

I'm wondering how can I convert a thread to a GUI thread? I couldn't find such a Win32 method to call.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the functions that deals with HWNDs will convert the thread to a UI thread automatically.

[`IsGUIThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isguithread) can be used to query and explicitly convert the current thread.

Comment: Can you provide a sample HWNDs function?

Comment: AdjustWindowRect maybe? There is no list of functions, this is an implementation detail.